# Sftp server logs "Failed password for <xxxx> from xxxx"

Tags: centos, authentication, sftp, sshd, pam

I use Java sftp client JSCH to connect sftp server, and the client throws "Auth failed" exception **occasionally**, and the sshd log shows "Failed password for  from xxxx" **occasionally** too.

I have confirmed that the sftp user and password are correct, so why it is **occasionally** wrong? More detail information below:

#### Environment

Client: Java = 1.7，jsch=0.1.50
Server: OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips

#### sshd_config

```
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV   
PasswordAuthentication yes 
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
MaxStartups 1000
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
Match Group sftp
ChrootDirectory /opt/bank/%u
ForceCommand    internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

#### /var/log/secure log

```
Mar 29 19:59:19 localhost sshd[30522]: debug1: Forked child 24126.
Mar 29 19:59:19 localhost sshd[24126]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Mar 29 19:59:19 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 79 sock 80
Mar 29 19:59:19 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Mar 29 19:59:19 localhost sshd[24126]: Connection from xx.xx.xx.xx port 39834
Mar 29 19:59:19 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version JSCH-0.1.50
Mar 29 19:59:19 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: no match: JSCH-0.1.50
Mar 29 19:59:19 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Mar 29 19:59:19 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Mar 29 19:59:21 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: user xxxx does not match group list sftp at line 134
Mar 29 19:59:21 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "xxxx"
Mar 29 19:59:21 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "xx.xx.xx.xx"
Mar 29 19:59:21 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Mar 29 19:59:22 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information\nKey table file '/etc/krb5.keytab' not found\n
Mar 29 19:59:22 localhost sshd[24126]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user xxxx (500) tally 4, deny 3
Mar 29 19:59:25 localhost sshd[24126]: debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for xxxx: Authentication failure
Mar 29 19:59:25 localhost sshd[24126]: Failed password for xxxx from 172.168.39.3 port 39834 ssh2
Mar 29 19:59:25 localhost sshd[24126]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user xxxx (500) tally 11, deny 3
```

So, I have no idea why sometimes it works, sometimes it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the answer:

```
pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user xxxx (500) tally 4, deny 3
```

You have `pam_tally2` configured on your server and it is making the password authentication fail. So from what you provide it looks like there are some bogus attempts to authenticate to SSH server and after you try to login with your app, account is already locked. But without more logs in context, it is hard to say.

Comment: But I do not know what the bogus is. There is only one client with the correct user and password. Where could I find more logs? How could I monitor the exact user and password, is there any other logs more than /var/log/secure?